# \includegraphics is not showing jpgs but is showing pngs

Tags: graphics, jpeg

I've just moved my PhD thesis from a Mac to a PC (hard drive corupted, thank God for backups).

Using Texworks, it compiles fine except for images, specifically all jpg images are missing. These are of course kept in the same folder.

I have also tried putting them directly into a minimal document. This compiles, but doesn't contain the image

```
\documentclass[]{article}


\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{Antibody_types.jpg}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you try if `\includegraphics{Antibody_types}` works?

Comment: :( it still doesn't

Comment: how are you producing output, pdftex or tex+dvips+ps2pdf ?

Comment: you should not get no image with no warning, what does the log file say for the above test file?

Comment: I get 2 badboxes, 0 warnings 0 errors

untitled-3.tex
10
Overfull \hbox (422.86687pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 10--11
[][]

untitled-3.tex
10
Overfull \hbox (422.86687pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 10--11
[][]

Comment: I'm using pdflatex+MakeIndex+Bibtex

Comment: \hbox (422.86687pt too wide)  is _very_ much too wide perhaps the image is off page, what happens with `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Antibody_types.jpg}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61264/discussion-between-abijah-and-david-carlisle).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved in comments and chat